# rsyslog filtering and forwarding

Tags: rsyslog

I'm trying to achieve filtering and forwarding using a rsyslog vm.

When I use

```
*.* @@192.168.1.100:514
```

It forwards all logs to that log server.

What I need to do is filter out logs that contain 'testing' and 'flow' and also prevent logs from localhost from being sent to the log server.

I have tried many ways of achieving this combination and failed. I just don't receive any logs to the destination once I use filters.

The remaining full contents of the rsyslog.conf is

```
# rsyslog configuration file

# For more information see /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-*/rsyslog_conf.html
# If you experience problems, see http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/troubleshoot.html

#### MODULES ####

# The imjournal module bellow is now used as a message source instead of imuxsock.
$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imjournal # provides access to the systemd journal
#$ModLoad imklog # reads kernel messages (the same are read from journald)
#$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

# Provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514

# Provides TCP syslog reception
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerRun 514

#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Where to place auxiliary files
$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf

# Turn off message reception via local log socket;
# local messages are retrieved through imjournal now.
$OmitLocalLogging on

# File to store the position in the journal
$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state

#### RULES ####
if $msg contains 'testing' then @@192.168.1.100:514
#*.* @@192.168.1.100:514
```

My configuration is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, notice that line `$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf`.  Basically it's saying that all `.conf` files will be included in that `rsyslog.conf` file you pasted.  So rather than putting your rule at the bottom of that file, I would advise adding another file, say `/etc/rsyslog.d/30-testing.conf` and putting your rule there.  This is more organized, and will be helpful if your syslog config grows in the future.

Other than that though, if it works without the filter, and thus ports/firewall isn't an issue, than it really should work -- your filter line looks fine.  You might have already done so, but maybe try:

```
:msg, contains, "testing"         @@192.168.1.100:514
```

Also, are you restarting the rsyslog service every time you change the configuration file?  You may need to do so.  Can you also post what version of rsyslog you're using?

Comment: Thank you Drew. I figured out it was not the rsyslog which was not working. The test message that i was sending was not long enough to match it. If you just send "testing" as a message the rule was not working. If you send "I am just testing" it works. I think the message part has some length condition after which it is matching.. I had to enable debug in the config file to figure this out. It works for me now and thank you so much for responding to my question

Comment: @Harry That's actually really interesting, it works for me just fine (but I'm only logging to a local file).  I have in my rsyslog config file:
`if $msg contains 'testing' then    /var/log/mylog.log` and after running the command `logger "testing"`, then in `mylog.log` I see the logline:
`May  9 14:56:25 myServerHostname root: testing`.  It gets logged fine, so it's strange it doesn't work for you.  I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 (rsyslog version: 5.8.6), if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm using Centos 7.2, besides im not logging to a file, I'm logging to another syslog server which is essentially just a daemon in my laptop. It just appends a text file here. Atleast I learned something new with rsyslog :)

Comment: @Harry, I have a local file in server machine (this is combination of all client), now I want to filter the data of this file, filter criteria might be severity, priority and any hard code text. I am newbie in this, how to fix this?